# JavaScript using async/await from a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a JavaScript class and I am trying to figure out how to use the new `async/await` keywords in the connect method.

```
module.exports = class {
    constructor(url) {
        if(_.isEmpty(url)) {
            throw `'url' must be set`;
        }

        this.url = url;
        this.client = new MongoClient(url, {
            useNewUrlParser: true
        });
    }

    connect() {
        this.client.connect(async (error) => {
            if(error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Essentially I want wait until `connect()` returns from the callback. I added `async` in front of the callback, but don't I need an `await` statement as well? I am getting a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` from Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If connect is an async function/returns a promise then you can await the call if you're calling it from within an async function, like so:

```
async connect() {
        await this.client.connect(async (error) => {
            if(error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: He may not need `async` in front of `(error) => {` anymore.

Comment: True, and depending on how connect is written it may not even need the error callback at all as it may already be rejected and then thrown by the awaited statement.